# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=L$, is there any reference that can tell the limit of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_na_n$ if $b_n$ is a decreasing sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we know that $\displaystyle \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty a_n=L$, is there any reference that can tell the limit of $\displaystyle \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty b_na_n$ if $b_n$ is a decreasing sequence?

Comment: If $\displaystyle\sum a_n <\infty$ and $b_n$ is decreasing sequence which converges to zero, then $\displaystyle\sum a_n b_n <\infty$.

Comment: Convergence of "product" requires only that partial sums of $a_n$ are bounded and $b_n$ is decreasing. This can be seen from so called "Abel's summation formula".

Comment: We can determine that the product series converges. When you wonder whether we can "tell the limit" it sounds like you want to know the actual value of the product series; that's clearly impossible.